# How to make mongo validate documents before insert or update in Vertx?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, vert.x

I'm newbie using Vertx, I'm building a basic Api Rest with Vertx + Mongo using Javascript.

I'm looking for some way to automaticly validate the incoming documents before insert or update (for example, something like schemas in Mongoose).

I got the following:

**POST entry point** Inserting a new cat

```
var BodyHandler = require("vertx-web-js/body_handler");
var Router = require("vertx-web-js/router");
var router = Router.router(vertx);
router.post("/cat")
    .produces("application/json")
    .handler(BodyHandler.create().handle)
    .handler(controller.createCat);
```

**Controller's function** Inserting a new cat

```
createCat: function (ctx) {
  var response = ctx.response();
  var body = ctx.getBodyAsJson() || {};

  console.log('inserting cat')

  connection.mongoClient.insert("cats", { name: body.name }, function (res, res_err) {
    if (res_err == null) {
      var id = res;
      console.log("Inserted cat with id " + id);
      response.putHeader("content-type", "application/json");
      response.end(JSON.stringify(id));
    } else {
      console.log('err')
      res_err.printStackTrace();
    }
  });
}
```

The problem is that I can insert empty documents resulting documents with only one field: the mongo ID.

**TL;DR - I want to know if there is some way to tell Mongo that name field is ALWAYS required.**

Solution I used:

```
mongoClient.runCommand("collMod", { collMod: "cats", validator: { $and: [ {"name": {$type: "string", $exists: true}} ] }, validationLevel: "strict", validationAction: "error" }, function(res, res_err) {
  if (res_err) res_err.printStackTrace()
  else console.log('The schema of cats collection has been updated')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mongodb there is a concept of validation with query filters for collection: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/#query-expressions

If the "name" field is always required, you can create your collection like this:

```
db.createCollection("cats", {
  validator: {
    $and: [ {"name": {$type: "string", $exists: true}} ]
})
```

Comment: It's not working, Vertx [doc say createCollection's second argument is a function](https://vertx.io/docs/jsdoc/module-vertx-mongo-js_mongo_client-MongoClient.html#createCollection) (callback function I guess?). I think that Vertx uses a small version of MongoDB Java Driver [Vertx Mongo guide](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-mongo-client/js/).

I found [this](http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/?com/mongodb/async/client/MongoDatabase.html#createCollection-java.lang.String-com.mongodb.async.SingleResultCallback-) but I coudn't make it to work.

Comment: i did not mean it to execute it with vertx mongo driver, you can simply use the mongo command line. But if you insist to run it with the vertx mongo driver, just use the runCommand function.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own schema in a separate json file, then create your own validation method when the context is provided by ur router.

I assume different endpoint has different validation.

you can also create a middleware using `gateleen`

you have plenty of options, mongoose its benefits but the whole point of using mongodb is not creating a schema. Therefore, u can assume that the request should have specific mandatory fields to validate.